# Automatically accept runtime permissions on Android Marshmalllow or above programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there a way to automatically accept permissions on a user's mobile and without the interaction of the user with the app? When the app launches, the permissions should be accepted automatically. Please suggest me any idea/hack to do it.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want run time permission then your target sdk version should be lolipop Doing so run time permisssion will not be required only one time permission while installing app will be required

Comment: I want all the permissions accepted automatically in android versions specially from lollipop to nouget. Normally, pop ups appear that asks users to accept permissions but I want to accept them automatically without the user's notice.

Comment: then sorrry it is not possible in any case

Comment: No problem, thanks for your response but I believe there must be a way to do it programmatically because everything has some hack available. Thanks

Comment: if you found a way in future please share with us well

Answer (score 3):

Yea its possible , For that you need change targetSdkVersion (SDK v26 or any version above to SDK v22) to targetSdkVersion SDK v22 in `build.gradle` , in this case it will not ask to user to grant perssion , it will take permission automatically and why its working because granting permission introduce in sdk 23 and above

Note :- it may be ask permission in OPPO phones , Vivo etc while runtime.

Sample Peoject Link :- https://github.com/kdblue/PermissionGranted

Answer (score 0):

> No problem if the solution is illegal but I want a way to do it

**Whats this mean?**

First of all this is impossible. If you are working on a technology then you have to follow its guidelines. 
The second thing is if your app targets `Android M` or greater then you have to follow the [Permission model](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) .

If your app target is below `Android M` then you do not have to ask for **Runtime permission**, the permissions will automatically granted on installation all at once.

**Note**:- Starting from Android M User can manually allow/disallow the permission to any third party app . So in that case you won't get `SecurityException` but your feature would not work .

**Conclusion:-** As you see your app is going to effect anyhow whether its targets low or high, So its better to follow the Permission model and make use of Android's new version's. As Android's new versions rolls out to more and more users, apps that request permissions at the time of installation will be viewed as un-maintained or poorly written, as users will expect not to have to agree to permissions up front, which leads to bad user experience .